# elasticsearch 5 nested term aggregation does not work

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested type mapping in my index:

```
  "actors": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "actor": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "actor_full_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

When i see the datas it looks to be ok

The request

```
 GET /test_index/film/_search
    {
      "size": 100,
      "_source": "actors.actor.actor_full_name"
    }
```

Give me this answer:

```
  "actors": {
            "actor": [
              {
                "actor_full_name": "Antonio BANDERAS"
              },
              {
                "actor_full_name": "Diane VENORA"
              },
              {
                "actor_full_name": "Omar SHARIF"
              },
              {
                "actor_full_name": "Vladimir KULICH"
              }
            ]
          },
...
```

I am trying to do a [nested  aggregation request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) on actor_full_name field

I am trying this request:

```
POST /test_index/film/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "actor_nested_agg_code": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "actors"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "code_actor_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "actor.actor_full_name.keyword",
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it appears to give me an incorect aswere :

```
 "aggregations": {
    "actor_nested_agg_code": {
      "doc_count": 1807,
      "code_actor_agg": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": []
      }
    }
  }
```

Do you see what i did wrong and how i could fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either didn't mean to make `actors` nested as well, or you overlooked that you have two `nested` fields in there:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "actor_nested_agg_code": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "actors"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "second_nested_actor": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "actors.actor"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "code_actor_agg": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "actors.actor.actor_full_name.keyword",
                "size": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```